# Redirecting with ajax but instead of redirect, my array is echoing

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to redirect the page after using ajax to validate my form. The problem is that instead of redirect or validation when I click the signup button I get a page with the text:

```
{"status":true,"message":"error","redirect":"..\/login-error-page.php"}
```

And in my error log:

```
[07-Jun-2017 01:04:24 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: errorEmpty in include/signup.inc.php

[07-Jun-2017 01:04:24 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: errorEmail in include/signup.inc.php
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong? I am new to ajax. Thanks in advance.

Index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Yahbang</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on('submit', '.signup-message', function () {

            $("#signup-form").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var first  = $("#signup-first").val();
                var last   = $("#signup-last").val();
                var email  = $("#signup-email").val();
                var pwd    = $("#signup-pwd").val();
                var submit = $("#signup-submit").val();

                $.ajax({
                    url:      'include/signup.inc.php',
                    type:     'POST',
                    data:     {first: first, last: last, email: email, pwd: pwd, submit: submit},
                    datatype: 'json',
                    success:  function (respond) {
                        if (!respond.status) {
                            alert(respond.message);
                        }
                        else
                            Window.Location.href = respond.redirect;
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="header_index">
        <div class="headerlogo">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Yahbang</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>


        <form id="login-form" class="loginform" action='include/login.inc.php' method='POST'>
            <input id="login-email" type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email'>
            <input id="login-pwd" type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Password'>
            <p><a href="forgotpassword.php">Forgot Password</a></p>
            <button id="login-submit" type='submit'>Login</button>
            <p class="login-message"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</header>

<form id="signup-form" class="signup" action='include/signup.inc.php' method='POST'>
    <input id="signup-first" type='text' name='first' placeholder='First Name'><br>
    <input id="signup-last" type='text' name='last' placeholder='Last Name'><br>
    <input id="signup-email" type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email'><br>
    <input id="signup-pwd" type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Password'><br>
    <button id="signup-submit" type='submit'>Sign Up</button>
    <p class="signup-message"></p>
</form>

<footer>
    <div class="footer_index">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="TermsofUse.php">Terms of Use</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

signup.inc.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../dbh.php';

$respond = [
    'status'   => true,
    'message'  => 'error',
    'redirect' => '../profile.php',
];

echo json_encode($respond);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);
    $last  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $pwd   = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

    $errorEmpty = false;
    $errorEmail = false;


    if (empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($pwd)) {
        echo "<span class='signup-error'>Please fill out all fields!</span>";
        $errorEmpty = true;
    } elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "<span class='signup-error'>Please enter a valid email address!</span>";
        $errorEmail = true;
    } else {
        $sql        = "SELECT email FROM user WHERE email='$email'";
        $result     = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $emailcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($emailcheck > 0) {
            echo "<span class='signup-error'>That email address already exists!</span>";
            $errorEmail = true;
        } else {
            $encryptpwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $sql        = "INSERT INTO user (first, last, email, pwd)
        VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email', '$encryptpwd')";
            $result     = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }
    }
}
?>

<script>
    $("#signup-first, #signup-last, #signup-email, #signup-pwd").removeClass("input-error");

    var errorEmpty = "<?php echo $errorEmpty; ?>";
    var errorEmail = "<?php echo $errorEmail; ?>";

    if (errorEmpty == true) {
        $("#signup-first, #signup-last, #signup-email, #signup-pwd").addClass("input-error");
    }

    if (errorEmail == true) {
        $("#signup-email").addClass("input-error");
    }

    if (errorEmpty == false && errorEmail == false) {
        $("#signup-first, #signup-last, #signup-email, #signup-pwd").val("");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You are trying to _access_ those two variables after the if statement block, so you should initialize them _outside_ of it as well.

Comment: Thanks. That solved my error issue. any advice on why I am getting my array $respond echoing in a new page instead of being used by my ajax?

Comment: Because you did not actually prevent the normal form submit.

Comment: sorry for so many questions, but i'm new to ajax and jquery. still learning. what would be the correct way to do it? so I know for future reference.

Comment: You already have a submit event handler set up with `$(document).on('submit', '.signup-message', function () {` - so why are you even calling `$("#signup-form").submit(function (event) {` inside of that again? Makes little sense. Subscribe to the event once, and prevent the default from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi try to add `error` in ajax to simulate error response from php

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'include/signup.inc.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {first: first, last: last, email: email, pwd: pwd, submit: submit},
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(respond){
        if (!respond.status) 
        {
            alert(respond.message);
        }
        else
            Window.Location.href = respond.redirect;
    },
    error: function(error){
        //methods here
    }
});
```